# AngularJS ng-repeat creates input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm wondering how can I use ng-repeat with `input` elements.
I have a `select` which have some queries `option`, whenever I choose a query I would like to check if there is one or multiple parameters that is required to input. Some queries need to input two parameters, how can I search for the word parameter and create inputs depend on the result I found.

This is my select:

```
<select ng-model="querySelect" ng-options="item.query as item.queryName for item in queries"></select>
```

and this is my input:

```
<input type="text" ng-show="querySelect.match('parameter')" ng-model="queryParaInput">
```

My Array:

```
"queries":[
 {"queryName":"View all meals","query":"select * from meal"},
 {"queryName":"Meal price more than","query":"select * from meal where price > parameter"},
 {"queryName":"Meal price between","query":"select * from meal where price  between parameter and parameter"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put one more input box:

```
<input type="text" ng-show="querySelect.match('between')" ng-model="queryParaInputBetween">
```

Comment: how can I search through `querySelect` for `parameter` word and create inputs depends on the result

Comment: set different model. Access it by $scope.queryParaInputBetween

Comment: can I do it dynamically? For example: If I found `parameter` word once only one `input` will be created, however if found `parameter` twice two `input` will be created, if I didn't find any no input will be created.

Answer (score 0):

When you get your data you can run it through once and create the necessary model structure.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "queryName": "View all meals",
    "query": "select * from meal"
  }, {
    "queryName": "Meal price more than",
    "query": "select * from meal where price > parameter"
  }, {
    "queryName": "Meal price between",
    "query": "select * from meal where price  between parameter and parameter"
  }];

  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value) {
    var count = value.query.split('parameter').length - 1; // this is just one of the way of counting how many times 'parameter' has occurred in the string

    value.param = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      value.param.push(""); // init each parameter's model to empty string
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller="Test">
  <div ng-repeat="query in data">
    {{query.query}}
    <div ng-repeat="param in query.param track by $index">
      Param {{$index + 1}}:
      <input type="text" ng-model="param">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```